# Eclipse error: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes on several projects

Tags: java, eclipse, manifest

I've googled but I haven't been able to find someone with a similar problem.  I am getting this error in eclipse on several of my own projects as well as eclipse jars like this one.  My project won't compile because of these issues.

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2012-09-04 17:17:18.695 !MESSAGE
>   Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in:
>   "org.eclipse.core.resources". !STACK 0 java.lang.SecurityException:
>   Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes    at
>   sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:240)
>     at
>   sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:193)
>     at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:305)     at
>   java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:216)    at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:341)    at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:406)    at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.ExternalLibraryCache.extractJar(ExternalModelManager.java:320)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.ExternalLibraryCache.getExtractedLibraries(ExternalModelManager.java:234)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.ExternalModelManager.getExtractedLibraries(ExternalModelManager.java:160)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PDEClasspathContainer.addExternalPlugin(PDEClasspathContainer.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.RequiredPluginsClasspathContainer.addPlugin(RequiredPluginsClasspathContainer.java:256)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.RequiredPluginsClasspathContainer.addDependency(RequiredPluginsClasspathContainer.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.RequiredPluginsClasspathContainer.addDependency(RequiredPluginsClasspathContainer.java:214)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.RequiredPluginsClasspathContainer.computePluginEntries(RequiredPluginsClasspathContainer.java:129)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.RequiredPluginsClasspathContainer.getClasspathEntries(RequiredPluginsClasspathContainer.java:88)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2695)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2853)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1958)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.computeExpandedClasspath(JavaProject.java:506)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.computeExpandedClasspath(JavaProject.java:528)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getExpandedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1563)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.computeClasspathLocations(NameEnvironment.java:93)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.(NameEnvironment.java:41)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.initializeBuilder(JavaBuilder.java:603)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:167)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:513)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:422)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.util.CoreUtility$BuildJob.run(CoreUtility.java:165)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

The webernets tells me that there's an issue with a specific jar file, but I've not encountered explanation that has this issue on several jar files.  I am using Helios service pack 2 and I'm using the same zip (for Helios) on another machine (and don't get these errors) so I don't think the issue is a corrupt file in the download.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002777

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the JRE used by Eclipse. Security exceptions are handled by the runtime, so it is possible the JRE you are using to run Eclipse does not match the libraries Eclipse uses to compile .