# JNI error: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jar, jar-signing

I have created my .jar file using `mvn package` command in the CMD, but when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
        at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:340)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:282)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:321)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:762)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.ensureInitialization(JarFile.java:1033)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.ensureInitialization(JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.java:72)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:883)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:848)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:780)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:675)
```

I tried many solutions like:

1- make sure that java and javac are the same version (17.0.2)

2-https://stackoverflow.com/a/34856095/17424390

But still I got the same error

My POM.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>DevicesHistoryInfoCards_Maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DevicesHistoryInfoCards_Maven</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://jmaven.com/maven/org.guppy4j/jdbc -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-digester3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.19.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://jmaven.com/maven/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-assembly-plugin -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>application.MainLauncher</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>application.MainLauncher</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>
                                application/application.MainLauncher
                            </mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[This is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002777/java-lang-securityexception-invalid-signature-file-digest-for-manifest-main-att) was suggested to me, but I did not understand how to do it although I have searched a lot for hoe to apply it.

Notes:
the project is javafx project, it uses maven, the java version is 17.0.2, the javac version is 17.0.2

> > > > > > > > **UPDATE_17/Mar/2022_THE_SOLUTION**

After 1 week of searching for a solution, I did the following

1- Add the `maven-dependency-plugin` like that:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>META-INF/*.SF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.RSA</excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

2- add the following to your 'maven-shade-plugin'(if you are using it) to the configuration section:

```
<filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
```

Comment: You need to rebuild and re-sign the JAR file. Something is wrong with its signature.

Comment: @user207421 how do I re-sign my JAR file ?

Comment: THE SOLUTION IS IN THE QUESTION

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this since this is a Maven question, but the duplicate target isn't, and frankly doesn't even look particularly reproducible.  Further, the question asker of this one appears to have found a solution, so reopening it would allow them to post it as an answer to their own question.

Comment: @M.Justin thanks for voting for opening the question again, unfortunately the question could not be opened