# Maven-shade-plugin has detected that some class files are present in two or more JARs

Tags: java, maven, javafx, maven-shade-plugin

I'm trying to use the **maven-shade-plugin** but I get a warning:

> javafx-controls-18.0.1-win.jar, javafx-graphics-18.0.1-win.jar,
> javafx-media-18.0.1-win.jar, javafx-web-18.0.1-win.jar define 1
> overlapping resource:
>
> - META-INF/substrate/config/resourcebundles javafx-graphics-18.0.1-win.jar, javafx-media-18.0.1-win.jar,
>   javafx-web-18.0.1-win.jar define 2 overlapping resources:
> - META-INF/substrate/config/jniconfig-x86_64-linux.json
> - META-INF/substrate/config/reflectionconfig-x86_64-linux.json javafx-base-18.0.1-win.jar, javafx-controls-18.0.1-win.jar,
>   javafx-graphics-18.0.1-win.jar define 1 overlapping resource:
> - META-INF/substrate/config/reflectionconfig.json maven-shade-plugin has detected that some class files are present in two or more JARs.
>   When this happens, only one single version of the class is copied to
>   the uber jar. Usually this is not harmful and you can skip these
>   warnings, otherwise try to manually exclude artifacts based on mvn
>   dependency:tree -Ddetail=true and the above output. See
>   https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

This watning is subject to change (possibly from my actions).

I tried to fix it with this, but it didn't work:

```
<filters>
    <filter>
        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
        <excludes>
           <exclude>META-INF/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </filter>
</filters>
```

I began to try to fix this warning due to the fact that shade-jar does not start due to an error:

> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run
> this application

Please tell me how to fix this error and run shade-jar?

My **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>TEST</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>TEST</name>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
        <javafx.version>18.0.1</javafx.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.co.caprica</groupId>
            <artifactId>vlcj</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.co.caprica</groupId>
            <artifactId>vlcj-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.test.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                    <source>18</source>
                    <target>18</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.test/com.test.Main</mainClass>
                            <launcher>TEST</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>TEST</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>TEST</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                            <compress>2</compress>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: See if this helps you: https://edencoding.com/runtime-components-error/

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71477520/jni-error-java-lang-securityexception-invalid-signature-file-digest-for-manife
Try the solution here (the solution is written in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this instead "maven-shade-plugin"

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.example.Launcher</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70809214/10946427